# How to duplicate an animated object, to have separate animations?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have modelled a garage door, five flaps that rise 'up and over'. I laboriously set key frames for five 'Empty's; each flap is parented to its Empty, the Position and Rotation use Delta Transforms. It works, and I'm pleased with it.

I need to duplicate this collection, so as to have several Garage Doors, each with its own animation (the same one, but triggered independently). When I duplicate the Door, the animation runs for both at the same time. How may I have the duplicated door (and others I'll need to do) run independently?

I'm a relative beginner in these giddy heights.

Comment: That's an easy one - go into each duplicate's keyframe strips in the Dopesheet and slide their keyframes left or right to stagger their start times.

Comment: PS to the above - I'm wondering if you wouldn't be better off making the Empties follow a curve and have the plates rotate around that?  Something like Tank-Tracks.

Comment: Thanks for that; I've understood.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos...   I'm rather surprised by the editing of my question. An explanation of the reasons might help me in future redactions. What are the 'rules' on this, please..?

Comment: Hi Dad, [this post should sum it up](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2463/why-is-saying-thanks-forbidden-here). Don't take it personally, edits are always about the post, never about the author

Answer (score 0):

You can either duplicate the animation as Edgel3D explains, or, in the *Dope Sheet* in *Action Editor* mode, push down the animation into the *Non Linear Animation* editor:

[image]

It will create as many strips as you have animated objects, now shift the strip of the object you want so that its animation begins later:

[image]

To bring back the original animation, select it again in the *Dope Sheet* or select a stip and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the extra method explained.